# R: simulating data with lmer and predict (or else)

Tags: r, lme4

I am fitting the following model

```
fit<- lmer(y ~ a + b + (1|c) + (1|a:d) , data=inputdata)
```

to real observations collected in "inputdata".
Now I want to generate various (1000) modelled datasets for a simulation based on the model parameters and the determined errors. I can use

```
pred <- predict(fit, newdata=list(a=val_a1, b=val_b1, c=val_c1, d = val_d1),
                allow.new.levels = TRUE)
```

but this always provides the same (the most likely, mean value). Is there a way to get a distribution of values, meaning to draw from a predicted distribution?

As asked by @Adam Quek a reproducable example:

```
    #creating dataset
    a <- as.factor(sort(rep(1:4,5 )))
    b <- rep(1:2,10)+0.5
    c <- as.factor(c( sort(rep(1:2,5)),sort(rep(1:2,5)) ))
    d <- as.factor(rep(1:5,4 ))
    a <- c(a,a,a)
    b <- c(b,b,b)
    c <- c(c,c,c)
    d <- c(d,d,d)
    y <- rnorm(60)
    inputdata = data.frame(y,a,b,c,d)

    # fitting the model   
    fit<- lmer(y ~ a + b + (1|c) + (1|a:d) , data=inputdata)

    # making specific predictions for a parameter set
    val_a1 = 1
    val_b1 = 2
    val_c1 = 1
    val_d1 = 4
    pred <- predict(fit, newdata=list(a=val_a1, b=val_b1, c=val_c1, d = val_d1),
                    allow.new.levels = TRUE)
    pred
```

what I obtain is: 
0.2394255

If I do it again

```
pred <- predict(fit, newdata=list(a=val_a1, b=val_b1, c=val_c1, d = val_d1),
                allow.new.levels = TRUE)
pred
```

I get of course:
0.2394255

but what I am searching for is a R function or routine that easily provides a suite of predictions that follow the distribution of my input values. Something like

```
for (i in 1:1000){
    pred[i] <- predict(fit, newdata=list(a=val_a1, b=val_b1, c=val_c1, d = 
               val_d1),allow.new.levels = TRUE)
}
```

and `mean(pred) = 0.2394255` but `sd(pred) != 0`

Comment: Please produce a reproducible example when you're asking a question. Also state clearly what your expected output is. In this case, you are you having problem with coming out with `val_XX`?

Comment: `?lme4::bootMer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alex W! bootMer does the job. Below for those who are interested the solution for the example:

```
m1 <- function(.) {
   predict(., newdata=inputdata, re.form=NULL)
}
boot1 <- lme4::bootMer(fit, m1, nsim=1000, use.u=FALSE, type="parametric")
boot1$t[,1]
```

where `boot1$t[,1]`now contains the 1000 predictions when using the parameter values defined in inputdata[1,]. 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html
was a helpful link.